# How to get the input text value from drop area?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Here its my code.

```
<div id="droparea">
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="world" />
    </div> 

    <div class="drag"> Example A </div>
```

Now i want to get the value(world) of input type when I Drop a "Example A" on drop area.
I used `var grd = ui.draggable.find('#name').html.value;` But it shows undefined.

Comment: `$('#name').val()`?

Comment: Wow . its working. Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for getting the input text value:

```
var inputText = ui.draggable.find("input[name=name]").val();
```